# Listar arquivos e pegar comentários PHP com script PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de uma ideia se possível ou um script que primeiramente lesse todos os arquivos de extensão `.php` de uma pasta pegando de cada um o comentário **PHP**, que fica no inicio das paginas ***que tiverem*** depois do **File Name:**.

```
<?php
/*
File Name: exemplo
*/
?>
```

e jogasse todos em um tag **html** `select option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução que utilizei.

```
function comment_titlePage() {
    $ap = WFOX_SITE_THEME . '/'; // PASTAS DO TEMA ATUAL

    if (is_dir($ap)) {
        // ABERTUR DA PASTA
        $dh = opendir($ap);

        if ($dh) {
            $arquivos = glob("$ap{*.php}", GLOB_BRACE);

            $mArray = array();
            foreach($arquivos as $php){
                $re = '/\<\?php\r\n\/\*\r\n(.*[A-z_])\r\n\*\//is';
                $str = file_get_contents($php);

                preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

                $return_matches = $matches[1][0];
                $loop_matches = preg_split("[File Name: ]",$return_matches);
                $mArray[$php] = $loop_matches[1];
            }

            return $mArray;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Opa,

Já tentou utilizar REGEX?

Por exemplo: [ CORRIGIDO ]

```
<?php

$re = '/\<\?php\r\n\/\*\r\n(.*[A-z_])\r\n\*\//is';
$str = '<?php
/*
File Name: exemplo
*/';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Não funcionou..

Comment: Fiz uma alteração. Veja se te ajuda agora, e desculpe!

Comment: Obrigado. Da início a uma logica.. ;)